# Term Set missing from available list in Managed Metadata column configuration

Tags: managed-metadata

Here I am trying to create a Managed Metadata column.

I get as far as Term Set Settings, and attempt to choose the term set I created about 15 minutes ago. But all I see are the term sets I created several days ago. I can't tell for certain if the recentness of the new Term Set has anything to do with this.

I've tried flipping back and forth between open and closed - no difference.
I'm not sure what else might be wrong.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can enlighten me.

Josh

Answer (score 1):

You would need to check in various places:

1. make sure your managed metadata service is functioning properly in CA.
2. In Managed Metadata Service PROXY (click next to the proxy line,
       choose properties and make sure all 3 checkboxes are checked -
       practically making your SA the default one, etc.)
3. Make sure your term store has adminitrators setup and that your account (used in the site) has required permissions on the term set.
4. Make sure your term set is not actually a Site Collection term set (created usually via a ) as these will only be visible at the level of that particular site collection where created.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd add one item to Marius's checklist:

"Make sure you're trying to build this column on the same farm as the one where the Managed metadata actually live."

D'oh.